# Mercurial: "abandoned transaction found - run hg recover". Recover does not work

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial

Using tortoise hg on windows, I did a pull from a repository on my local drive to a repository on a usb stick.

During the pull i guess there was a glitch in the usb-connection because it got aborted half way through.

Now i can't pull again. I get the message: `abandoned transaction found - run hg recover`

When i run hg recover i get the following message:

```
rolling back interrupted transaction
** unknown exception encountered, details follow
** report bug details to http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/
** or mercurial@selenic.com
** Python 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.6.3)
** Extensions loaded: fixfrozenexts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 36, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 16, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 34, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 54, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 494, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 355, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 545, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 499, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 492, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 420, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 2869, in recover
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 606, in recover
  File "mercurial\transaction.pyo", line 173, in rollback
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

If i try to rollback manually i get this message: `no rollback information available`

This time i can quite easily just delete the whole backup on my stick and do a fresh pull because the repo is small and the usb-stick does not contain any other changes. But what if this happens on a larger repo where i can't afford to restart from scratch? How can i recover the repo?

Comment: There is no guarantee that recovery will be able to handle all types of corruption, sometimes your repository really is hosed beyond repair, and a backup/reclone is all you can do. I assume you're ensuring you always ask Windows to eject/close your USB drive before unplugging it?

Comment: Of course i always try to do safe removal but this time the wire was attached loosely. Can this really cause the whole repo to go out of control? I thought everything was done with transactions ala sql so you could always roll back if something goes bad.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced a similar issue and [reported it as a bug](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue3290), and the developer on the report suggested the problem is a corrupt journal. As described in the bug report, you can run `hg verify` to see the last "good" commit, and use `hg clone -r <#>` to recover up until that commit.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is actually a bug in the code source. You should report the error to the Mercurial team like said in the error message.

Comment: I agree. Had the same issue for mercurial version `3.0+3`- reverted to version `2.5.2`: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/tortoisehg-2.7.1-hg-2.5.2-x64.msi and the rollback command passed.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the TeamCity CI and Deployment server, so, probably, this is another issue, but I have [posted the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593631/1114934) to the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475704/how-to-run-hg-recover-command-on-a-remote-repository).